# Bootstrap column height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm learning Bootstrap and hoping it will make building attractive page designs simpler for me.

I'm struggling to understand these two examples:

Bootstrap 3: http://codepen.io/rhutchinson/pen/WpxvWO

Bootstrap 4: http://codepen.io/rhutchinson/pen/aJZvKb

Since these are identical other than the version of Bootstrap used, I'm assuming that extending column height to the height of the `.row` is a new feature of Bootstrap 4.

Is there any way to replicate one version's behavior as to this issue while using the other version? If so, what would be the best way to go about doing that?

I'd like to understand these dimensional behaviors in order to give myself a better concept of front-end development, which doesn't come as naturally to me as the logic of back-end scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the `same column height is native support` in `bootstrap 4`, as bootstrap 4 uses `flex box`.

You can easily achieve the same behaviour if you use flex for bootstrap 3 by using the below example--

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bord {
  border-style: solid;
}

.row-eq-height {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-sm-3 text-center bord">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x140" class="center-block" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 text-center bord">
        <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 text-center bord">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x140" class="center-block" />
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE**

As mentioned by @ZimSystems `display: flex;` works for full height, but it breaks the responsive behavior of the Bootstrap 3 row and columns .

[Learn about flexbox here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Learn about the above example of .row-eq-height here](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/)

Hope this helps to clear your understanding!

Comment: `display: flex;` works for full height, but it breaks the responsive behavior of the Bootstrap 3 row and columns

Comment: I know that..I just tried to explain how it can be achieved..I am adding your suggestion to the answer. Thanks for the insight.