# Responsive content match to image height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The page is dived to two sections. Responsive image on left side and my content goes right side. I just want to set the content section height will be same as image height at any resolution. (Not in mobile version) But right now it looks like this. 
I tried with this codes.

```css
img {
 width:100%;
}

.about-section {
 height: 450px;
}
.about-content {
 padding: 60px;
 height: 100%;
 display: table;
 background: #efefef;
}
.inner {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.nopadding {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">
     <img src="https://c.tadst.com/gfx/750x500/computer-key-about-help.jpg?1" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 about-section nopadding">
     <div class="about-content">
      <div class="inner">
       <h3>WE BREATHE WEB TECHNOLOGY</h3>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum venenatis diam, et tempor est maximus a. Duis malesuada Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum venenatis diam, et tempor est maximus a. Duis malesuada Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum venenatis diam, et tempor est maximus a. Duis malesuada Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum venenatis diam, et tempor est maximus a. Duis malesuada Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum venenatis diam, et tempor est maximus a. Duis malesuada Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum venenatis diam, et tempor est maximus a. Duis malesuada</p>
      </div>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: where is your html

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to have the background retain that gray color? If so, there's a pretty simple way: move `background: #efefef;` to `.row`. Or if you need greater specificity (e.g. if you have other instances of `.row` on the page), just add an extra class to the `<div class="row">` element, and apply that `background` property to it.

Comment: But how can I center my content with the image?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `padding-bottom` to your content, and then possibly change the font size of your words. I don't know if it will work, because I don't have your image, but I think you should try it. I hope you find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just add negative margin to your columns.. the column heights will become same.

```
.row{
overflow: hidden; 
  }


 [class*="col-"]{
margin-bottom: -99999px;
padding-bottom: 99999px;
 }
```

**Working example**

```css
img {
 width:100%;
}

.about-section {
 height: 450px;
}
.about-content {
 padding: 60px;
 height: 100%;
 display: table;
 background: #efefef;
}
.inner {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.nopadding {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.row{
    overflow: hidden; 
}

[class*="col-md-6"]{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">
     <img src="https://c.tadst.com/gfx/750x500/computer-key-about-help.jpg?1" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 about-section nopadding">
     <div class="about-content">
      <div class="inner">
       <h3>WE BREATHE WEB TECHNOLOGY</h3>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum venenatis diam, et tempor est maximus a. Duis malesuada Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum venenatis diam, et tempor est maximus a. Duis malesuada Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum venenatis diam, et tempor est maximus a. Duis malesuada Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum venenatis diam, et tempor est maximus a. Duis malesuada Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum venenatis diam, et tempor est maximus a. Duis malesuada Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum venenatis diam, et tempor est maximus a. Duis malesuada</p>
      </div>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

**note**

You can use flexbox approach but that will break the responsiveness of your page.

[Refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590863/bootstrap-column-height/42590927#42590927)

Answer (score 0):

Images don't work in this responsive way, so you're better off using a background-image. The set a min-height on the image div so that is still appears on small screens. Use `flexbox` to make the row same height.

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/iBjwmWLmWT

```
.img {
    background-image:url(https://c.tadst.com/gfx/750x500/computer-key-about-help.jpg?1);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 270px;
}
.about-section {
    background: #efefef;
}
.about-content {
    padding: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .row {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/iBjwmWLmWT